# How to compare values in an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I have an array

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How do I compare the first with the second value, the second with the third etc.

The only thing I could come up with is this (which is rather ugly)

```
compared = array.each_with_index.map do |a,i| 
  array[i+1].nil? ? nil : array[i] - array[i + 1]
end

compared.compact # to remove the last nil value
```

What I want is

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Is there a nice "ruby way" of achieving this? without using all the ugly `array[i]` and `array[i+1]` stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.each_cons(2).map { |a,b| a - b }
# => [-1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Enumerable#inject：

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = []
a.inject{|i,j| b<< i-j; j}
p b
```

result：

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1]
```